# iOS 8.1..camera roll and photostream / deleted pictures

Tags: iphone, ios, photos.app, photos, photo-stream

Before the update, photos saved to camera roll would automatically go to photostream, too. You could then delete them from camera roll but they would remain on your photostream.

Now, you can still add photos just like you could, but as soon as you delete them from your camera roll, they are also simultaneously deleted from your photostream.

Any help on how to keep your deleted camera roll photos on your photostream?

Answer (score 1):

Apple apparently didn't realise just how many photos people were going to want to keep online, so they've dramatically reduced the retention.
If you want to keep photos, don't keep them on iCloud, keep them on your computer.